# Unable to run the spring boot program

Tags: sql, spring-boot, hibernate, hikaricp

I want to run the spring boot program but it's always throwing the error like *communication link failure*
I also change the port number and also added the tomcat dependency but still I m getting the same error

[image]

Comment: I hope, you have checked the connection settings for MySQL-connection

Comment: Please [don't upload textual content as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13447)

Comment: yes i check sql connection as well and at the first it will start the error throwing from "exception during pool initialization spring boot"